# How do you disable the special meaning of the ^ character in grep [] syntax?

Tags: regex, grep

Suppose, I have a file like below:

```
aaa1bbb
aaa^bbb
aaa\bbb
aaa%bbb
aaa*ccc
aaa(ccc
aaa)bbb
```

I want to find all lines that contain either `^` or `%` and then `bbb`. My expected results:

```
aaa^bbb
aaa%bbb
```

When I execute `grep '[^%]bbb' t1` I have received

```
aaa1bbb
aaa^bbb
aaa\bbb
aaa)bbb
```

which is completely correct. `^` is metacharter in grep `[]`syntax. I have all the results except `%bbb` regex. I understand this.  I have tried to disable metacharacter with `\` like this: `grep '[\^%]bbb' t1` I have received:

```
aaa^bbb
aaa\bbb
aaa%bbb
```

Why I got line `aaa\bbb` in the results? **The problem is: How do you disable the special meaning of the `^` character in grep `[]` syntax?** Is it possible without using `fgrep` or other workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a `^` literal char inside a bracket expression, put it NOT at the start of it:

```sh
grep '[%^]bbb' t1
```

This is part of the so-called "smart placement" technique, e.g. to use a `]` inside a bracket expression it must be placed at the start of a bracket expression, and `-` should be either at the start or end of the bracket expression.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/56wD5g):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='aaa1bbb
aaa^bbb
aaa\bbb
aaa%bbb
aaa*ccc
aaa(ccc
aaa)bbb'
grep '[%^]bbb' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
aaa^bbb
aaa%bbb
```